# Is There Any Way to Choose a Thumbnail for Video Upload?

Tags: facebook, video, upload, thumbnails

Hello Graph API experts,

I am developing an application where users can upload videos to their walls.  Now, is there any way with Graph API to specify which frame (at how many seconds) you want used for generating the videos' thumbnails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither the frame nor the seconds.  You can specify the picture to use via the `picture` "*The URL for the thumbnail picture for the video*" property of the video object. See https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

Comment: Could you please describe how can I use picture property of the video object to specify a custom thumbnail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this answer cant be correct.
You cant use picture property to set thumbnail for video